# C# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement Unknown error (0x80005000) UserPrincipal.IsMemberOf()

Tags: c#, active-directory

Similar to the problem in the following MSDN thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-MY/csharplanguage/thread/4c9fea6c-1d0a-4733-a8ac-e3b78d10e999

I am trying to verify whether or not a given user is a member of a group, and our existing functional solutions are too slow (13-16 seconds) and I'm trying to speed it up. I currently have:

```
public bool IsMemberAD(string userName, string groupName)
{
    var pc = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Domain);
    var user = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType.SamAccountName,
                                                 userName.ToLower());
    var group = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, groupName);

    if (group == null || user == null) return false;

    return user.IsMemberOf(group);    
}
```

What makes this interesting is that it only returns an error when the user is not in the group directly, but rather a member of a group that is within the target group.

For example:

Steve and Sam are two users, and GroupParent and GroupChild are two groups. Steve and GroupChild are members of GroupParent. Sam is a member of GroupChild. If I call this function on (Steve, GroupParent), it returns true. If I call it on (Sam, GroupParent), I get an error. If I call it on ("fdkjskghkf", GroupParent) it returns false.

I linked an article above with similar issues, but his solution did not work for me, I still got the same error. Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Jon Theriault [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/4c9fea6c-1d0a-4733-a8ac-e3b78d10e999) the following code fixed this problem for me.

```
string strName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; // "MW\\dalem"
// This is here because of a .Net error that gets 0x80005000 on "isUser = user.IsMemberOf(groupU);"
string domainName = strName.Split('\\')[0]; 
var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
```

Answer (score 2):

I remember when I wrote similar code I did run into some strange issues.  I'm not sure exactly why your call is failing but you can turn your problem around and do something like:

```
return group.GetMembers(true).Contains(user);
```

Comment: This is technically functional, but is very slow. The code I posted (when it doesn't break) finishes in 1.5 seconds or so, but return "group.GetMembers(true).Contains(user);" takes 10ish. I'm assuming this has to do with recursive checking?

Comment: I suppose it depends on the size and complexity of your AD.  I work at a medium size company and both queries return in under a second.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try somethig like this :

```
public bool IsMemberAD(string userName, string groupName)
{
  PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WM2008R2ENT:389", "dc=dom,dc=fr", "jpb", "pwd");

  /* Retreive the user principal
   */
  UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userName);
  if (user == null) return false;

  /* Retreive the group principal
   */
  GroupPrincipal targetGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, groupName);
  if (targetGroup == null) return false;

  /* Look for all the groups a user belongs to
   */
  PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> allGroups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

  var grp = (from g in allGroups
             where g.Sid == targetGroup.Sid
             select g).FirstOrDefault();

  return (!(grp == null));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested. Using DirectorySearcher with the following filter is approx 60% faster.

string filter = string.Format("(&(distinguishedName={1})(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0}))", dnOfUser, dnOfGroup);

The filter will traverse upwards and not just the parent of the user.

Answer (score 0):

GetAuthorizationGroups() does not find nested groups.

To really got all groups a given user is member of included nested groups try this:

```
using System.Security.Principal

private List<string> GetGroups(string userName)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(userName);

    foreach (IdentityReference group in wi.Groups)
    {
        try
        {
            result.Add(group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }

    result.Sort();
    return result;
}
```

Use Try/Catch because I had some exceptions in a very large AD (half a million objects) with 2 out of 200 groups because my some SIDs (Translate does SID -> Name conversion) were no longer available.
In our huge AD is only takes < 1 second.